# Django get_or_create trying to create row, throwing IntegrityError?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working in Django 1.7 and Postgres, and using the ORM to create some new rows. I am using `get_or_create` as follows:

```
    p, created = Practice.objects.get_or_create(
        code=row[1],
        name=row[2],
        address1=row[3],
        address2=row[4],
        address3=row[5],
        address4=row[6],
        postcode=row[7]
    )
```

But when I try to run this I get:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
DETAIL:  Key (code)=(A82057) already exists
```

What's this about? I thought the point of `get_or_create` was to only try to create new rows if they didn't already exist.

My model looks like this:

```
class Practice(TimeStampedModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    app_label = 'frontend'
    ordering = ['name']
```

Is it something to do with the fact that I've set a manual primary key? I can't see anything [in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) about this restriction.

Comment: "Is it something to do with the fact that I've set a manual primary key? I can't see anything in the Django docs about this restriction."

No? That's part of the docs you linked to:

"The get_or_create() method has similar error behavior to create() when you’re using manually specified primary keys. If an object needs to be created and the key already exists in the database, an IntegrityError will be raised."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`get_or_create` attempts to do a get with *all* of the parameters you pass, not just the PK. So if there is an object with a matching PK but a different postcode, for example, the get will fail so a create will be attempted - but, since you have a manual PK, it will try to create a duplicate one using the data you have passed.

Generally speaking using a non-autoincrementing PK is a bad idea. But if you are just trying to look up against the PK only, use the `defaults` argument:

```
p, created = Practice.objects.get_or_create(
    code=row[1],
    defaults={
        'name': row[2],
        'address1': row[3],
        'address2': row[4],
        'address3': row[5],
        'address4': row[6],
        'postcode': row[7]
    })
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `defaults={'name':row[2], 'address1':row[3] ...}` instead of the equal to sign?